# Adding an interval column to data

Tags: r

I have this data frame

```
x <- data.frame("age" = c(1,5,11,12,13,21,25,36,35))
```

I want to add a class column with the interval of the age. That looks like the example below

```
x$class <-
```

Desired outcome

```
age class
1   [0-10]
5   [0-10]
11  [11-20]
12  [11-20]
13  [11-20]
21  [21-30]
25  [21-30]
36  [31-40]
35  [31-40]
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following using `cut()`

```
x$class <- cut(x$age, breaks = seq(0,100,10), include.lowest = TRUE)

#   age   class
# 1   1  [0,10]
# 2   5  [0,10]
# 3  11 (10,20]
# 4  12 (10,20]
# 5  13 (10,20]
# 6  21 (20,30]
# 7  25 (20,30]
# 8  36 (30,40]
# 9  35 (30,40]
```